# Starting Plawywright Test Browser

Tags: browser, e2e-testing, playwright

guys. I'm trying to set up e2e testing using Playwright. I'm following along these steps ([enter link description here](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro)) and I can see the tests are passing but I'd like to see the browser window so I can try and interact with the elements. How can I make the test runner open a browser window or tab?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the Debug mode by adding --debug to you command e.g.:

```
npx playwright test example --debug
```

This allows you to Debug through your Tests step by step.

Or you can change your config to run in headed mode by setting

```
headless:false
```

In you playwright.config.ts

Comment: Thank you, bro. Is there any way I can interrupt the test case manually? I'd like to click something within the test browser run and check the output...

Comment: If you use the Playwright-Debugger  you should be able to go through your test step by step. If you use VSCode I can also recommend  the extension provided by playwright (https://playwright.dev/docs/getting-started-vscode). If you scroll through the page you can also see a guide for debugging with the extension. This should allow you to set break points and inspect elements in your test browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a global configuration file called playwright.config.ts which goes in project root, a basic example of which looks like below. Note the headless: false in the 'use' section. Change the 'baseURL' to what you want to test.

```
// playwright.config.ts

import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  reporter: [['list'], ['html', { open: 'never' }]],
  workers: 1,
  use: {
    baseURL: http://playwright.dev,
    headless: false,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
      },
    },
  ],
};
export default config;
```

In your test, because you have a baseURL set in config, you just need to call the following to navigate to that url:

```
// mytest.spec.ts

import { test } from '@playwright/test';

  test('Do something...', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. Is there any way I can interrupt the test case manually? Like, click a button mid-test? I'd like to click something within the test browser run and check the output.

Comment: @DevYego Do you mean like debugging the test?  If you are using node/typescript playwright with vs code, there are a number of ways to achieve that.  See the [vs code playwright test runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) which is one way of starting a test with debug.

Other way is to add breakpoints in your code and then run the test from a Javascript Debug Terminal.  The code will break when the breakpoint is hit allowing you to inspect vars etc.  Sorry if I did not understand your question :)

Comment: Hey @AJG, I figured it I used slowMo, I could interact with the page mid-test and check if the tests pass. However, I don't know the implication of this in case of form input. Thanks for the tip btw. I found that I could  pass the --headed flag too when running the tests and the browser will show up.